# add field in admin>content that show if entity is translated

Tags: views, entities, i18n-l10n

I'm looking for a field that i can add in the admin>content view.
I want to know if the entity (News items) is translated or not. (Dutch(default) and English)
Now i always have to click edit article to see if the article is translated.

Search for hours on the internet but no result.  (i did installed the admin view module so i could edit the admin>content view)

Hopefully someone could help me out with this.

Comment: You could write a custom field (hook_views_data()) that checks what languages are available for the given nid (custom query) and return them (with/without links). Then add this field in your admin views.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm fairly new to drupal code, so if possible i want to solve this without any code. (unless you have a working example for me?)

Comment: I don't know of an out of the box solution for this, i'm sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You can install the [Admin Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/admin_views) module and override the view on /admin/content by adding a field that shows if the node has been translated or not.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. i already did what you suggested, however i cannot find the right field that displays if the node is translated or not. Maybe i'm missing something.

Comment: Please take a look at https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/11918318/Screenshot%20from%202015-02-10%2011%3A43%3A22.png

Comment: I tried this, however this doesn't result as i would expect. If i have i know a node is translated it says "Yes" if i create a new node and doesn't translate it it still says "Yes"